# Ping from bash-script unknown host

Tags: bash, ping

I have a file full of hostnames - one in each line.
Now I'd like to check if these hostnames exist (and eventually delete them from the file if not).
I already fail at the first part:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read host; do
  ping -c1 "$host"
done <hosts
```

Only gives me

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

(put google.com in the file for testing)
I also tried removing the quotes - no effect.
However when running the command from a terminal that's what I get:

```
 $ ping -c1 "google.com"
   PING google.com (173.194.112.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
   ...
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: Your easiest approach is to loop through each in the file with say `ping -c 2 "$ip" && echo "$ip" >> tmpfile`. That will leave you with a `tmpfile` that contains all valid ip addresses. You can then move or rename the original and rename `tmpfile` to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your `hosts` file is in DOS line endings format (CR-LF line endings), so `read` fills variable with `google.com\r`.

Simplest way would be to convert file to UNIX line endings with `dos2unix hosts`.

Comment: @chris137: Try this: `dos2unix <hosts | while read -r host; do ping -c1 "$host"; done`

Comment: I'm confused, what is the concern over dos line ending? Does `ping` not work regardless?

Comment: `"google.com"` and `"google.com\r"` are different strings, and name resolution for latter wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing and I ended up with this script which you may find nice and useful. Still working on the part to try and recognize the "ping: unknown host hostname.co.hk" but that's okay.

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    cat list | while read domains; do
                reply=$(ping -c 1 $domains| grep -E '(from)' | wc -l)
                if [ $reply == 1 ]; then
                        DOMAIN=$(ping -c 1 $domains |grep 64 |awk '{print$4}')
                        IP=$(ping -c 1 $domains | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | head -1)
                        echo "$domains -> $DOMAIN -> $IP" >> ping.log;echo "$domains -> $DOMAIN -> $IP"
                else
                        echo "-----------------ping failed, verify domain name"
                fi 
done 
cat ping.log
```